# iOS: Create a instance of uncertain class in runtime

Tags: ios, runtime

Here is my goal:
I write a DDButtonView to provide others to use. DDButonView uses DDButton or subclass of DDButton.
I want others to subclass the DDButton, and custom it as others want. Finally others pass the subclass to DDButtonView.
Some kind like UITableView use UITableViewCell, users can subclass the cell and register the cell to table view, And I think the table view is using the subclass passed by users, creating it, using it in the runtime.
In this goal, I have to use a subclass of DDButton in runtime. I will create instance of the subclass and use it method, how to do it?
Thanks ahead!

One more question: if there is no way to do it, plz tell me too.

Comment: IF anyone knows where is the example to do it, plz tell me the url, thx.

Comment: it sounds like you need to use [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) but i find your question quite difficult to understand what exactly you want

Comment: @Fonix sorry for my poor writing. Like the UITableView, it use subclass of UITableViewCell in it. When we use table view, we just register the subclass of UITalbeViewCell. My goal is some kind like that.